# How to write expression with Square brackets in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, expression

Following is expression which is returning error even while running:

```
<c:set value="${MoneyForm.money.policy.policies[${loopIndex-1}].amount}" var="amountEuro" />

 javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression
```

This statement is in between "< for:each >" loop so loopIndex-1 is used.

Could someone please help in correcting it? Please give more precise solution as i need to do same with around 20 - 30 objects

Answer (score 2):

You have nested ELs, which is not a valid syntax. No need of encapsulating `looindex-1` again with curly brackets.

Try with

```
${MoneyForm.money.policy.policies[loopIndex-1].amount}
```

Also if your  c:forEach is like below

```
<c:forEach items="${Collection}" var="item" varStatus="loopindex">
</c:forEach>
```

here, if you want to access zero based index, use `loopindex.index`, if you want to access 1 based index, use `loopindex.count`, also `var="item"` , gives you current item in the collection being iterated